# How to read a BigDecimal type in spark sql

Tags: scala, apache-spark

What is the correct `DataType` to use for reading from a schema listed as `Decimal` - and with underlying java type of `BigDecimal` ?

Here is the schema entry for that field:

```
-- realmId: decimal(38,9) (nullable = true)
```

When I tried a `java.lang.Long` it ends up with the following error:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.math.BigDecimal cannot be cast to java.lang.Long
```

I noticed there is a `DecimalType` but it extends `AbstractDataType` and not `DataType` and it is not clear how to specify it as a return type.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the pickle. It's actually the way match `DecimalType` that is weird.

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._
import org.apache.spark.sql.{Row, SparkSession}

val spark: SparkSession = SparkSession.builder().getOrCreate()
val sc: SparkContext = spark.sparkContext

def rg(r: Row, fname: String, ftype: DataType = StringType) = ftype match {
  case StringType => r.getString(r.schema.fieldIndex(fname))
  case DecimalType() => r.getDecimal(r.schema.fieldIndex(fname))
  case _ => "error"
}
```

Let's now test that. First we need to create our decimal type as followed :

```
val decimalType : DecimalType = DataTypes.createDecimalType(15, 10)
val sch = StructType(StructField("x1", StringType, true) :: StructField("x2", decimalType, true) :: Nil)

val row = sc.parallelize(Seq("abc,0.352", "def,0.27", "foo,8.35", "bar,-153.890"))
  .map(x => x.split(",")).map(x => Row(x(0), BigDecimal.decimal(x(1).toDouble)))

val df = spark.createDataFrame(row, sch)
// df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [x1: string, x2: decimal(15,10)]
```

Let's check now what that function does :

```
println(rg(df.first(), "x2", decimalType))
// 0.3520000000
```

Comment: Isn't `BigDecimal.decimal(x(1).toDouble)` lossy? You should rather `BigDecimal(x(1).toString)`, shouldn't you?

Comment: That is true about using `toString` in preference to `toDouble`